# Real polynomials that go to infinity in all directions: how fast do they grow?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ be a polynomial. Define property $\mathbf{P}$ to be the property that there exists a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and a positive number $\kappa$ such that for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus K$ we have $f(\mathbf{x}) > \kappa$. Clearly, $f$ having property $\mathbf{P}$ implies $2d = \deg f$ is even. For a positive number $R$ define

$$\displaystyle m_f(R) = \inf_{R \leq \lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert_2 \leq 2R} f(\mathbf{x}).$$

Is the following statement true?

Suppose $f \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ has property $\mathbf{P}$ and $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} m_f(R) = \infty$. Does there exist $1 \leq r \leq d = (\deg f)/2$ and a positive number $\delta$ such that

$$\displaystyle f(\mathbf{x}) - \delta \left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_j^{2r} \right)$$

has property $\mathbf{P}$?

Edit: As remarked in the comments by MattF, the supposition that $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty} m_f(R) = \infty$ supersedes property $\mathbf{P}$.

Comment: Can you omit the hypothesis that $f$ has property P? It seems to follow from the hypothesis on $m_f$.

Comment: @MattF. And, as f = 10 has property P, P does not imply $m_f$.  So P is strictly weaker than $m_f \rightarrow \inf$

Comment: @Yakk what he meant is that the hypothesis that $m_f(R) \rightarrow \infty$ is strictly stronger than property P. I will make a note of this in the original post, but otherwise will leave the question in tact because that reflects how I thought about this problem.

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao Oh, I was just double checking that they where not equivalent.  :)  But they aren't.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The assumption "$\lim_{R\to\infty}m_f(R)\to\infty$" already includes $\bf P$ as remarked in comments, and it is the same as $\lim_{\|x\|\to\infty} f(x)=+\infty$, that is: **$f$ is a coercive polynomial**. You are asking whether a coercive polynomial in $n$ variables needs to go to infinity at least quadratically: the answer is no: *the order of coercivity* of a coercive polynomial may be an arbitrarily small positive number.

Check e.g. this article,  [How fast do coercive polynomials grow?](http://num.math.uni-goettingen.de/preprints/files/2017-1.pdf) (section 4 for examples). In particular (proposition 19), even in two variables, for any $k\in\mathbb N_+$,
$$f(x,y)=x^2+(y-x^{2k})^2$$
is coercive and has order of coercivity $1/k$, that is  $f(z)/{\|z\|^\theta}\to\infty$ as $\|z\|\to+\infty$,  for $\theta<1/k$, but for no $\theta>1/k$ (just because along the curve $y=x^{2k}$ one has $f(x,y)=x^2=y^{1/k}$, so that $f(z)/{\|z\|^{1/k}}=O(1)$)