# Lower bound for coercive polynomials, II

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

This is a refinement of my earlier question ([Lower bound for coercive polynomials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449389/lower-bound-for-coercive-polynomials)). This time, I ask the same question but for the exponent 1. Indeed, the question is: given a coercive polynomial $f \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$, whether there exist constants $c_1 > 0, c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\displaystyle f(x_1, \cdots, x_n) > c_1 \min\{ |x_1|, \cdots, |x_n|\} - c_2$$

The example given by Christian Remling does not exclude the exponent 1, but does exclude every exponent larger than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Drawing up on the example of Chritian Remling, taking
$$
  P(x, y) = (x^2 - y^{2 k + 1})^2 + y,
$$
with $k \in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$
we have
$$
  \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{P (t^{2k + 1}, t^2)}{\Vert (t^{2k + 1}, t^2)\Vert^q}
= \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{t^2}{\sqrt{t^{4k + 2} + t^4}^q} > 0
$$
if and only if
$$
  q \le \frac{2}{2k + 1}.
$$

On the other hand we have
$$
 \lim_{\Vert (x, y)\Vert \to \infty} P (x, y) = \infty;
$$
this follows from the following facts:

- If $y^{2k + 1} \ge x^2/2$, then $y \ge 0$,
  $$
    P(x, y) \ge y
  $$
  and
  $$
    \Vert (x, y)\Vert^2 \le 2 y^{2k + 1} + y^2.
  $$
- If $y^{2k + 1} \le x^2/2$ and $y \ge 0$, then
  $$
    P(x, y) \ge \frac{x^4}{4}
  $$
  and
  $$
    \Vert (x, y)\Vert^2 \le x^2 + \Bigl(\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigr)^\frac{2}{2 k + 1}.
  $$
- If $y \le 0$, then
  $$
    P(x, y) \ge x^4 + y^{4k + 2} + y.
  $$

Comment: Here $P(x,y)\ge|y|-c$, where $c:=-\min_{y\le0}(y^{4k+2}+2y)\in\mathbb R$. So, the example does not seem to be working.

Comment: I don’t think this answers my question. My question concerns whether the lower bound always holds, not that it holds for some example.

Comment: Sorry. Indeed, I overlooked the min in the question.